# multiple definition of a function

Tags: c++, macros

I defined a function to show a message when debug flags are off in a header file as below:

```
#ifdef  NDEBUG

#define debug_msg(expr, msg)        (static_cast<void>(0))

#else /* Not NDEBUG.  */

#ifndef SHOW_DEBUG_H_
#define SHOW_DEBUG_H_

#include <stdio.h>
void _show_in_debug(const char *_file, unsigned int _line,
        const char *_function, const char *_msg)
{
    printf("%s\t%d\t%s\t%s\n", _file, _line, _function, _msg);
    fflush(NULL);
}

#endif

#define debug_msg(expr, msg)                \
  ((expr)                               \
   ? _show_in_debug(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, msg)  \
   : static_cast<void>(0))

#endif
```

when I include the header in more than a file, I get the following error:

> multiple definition of `_show_in_debug(char const*, unsigned int, char
>   const*, char const*)'

I don't exactly know what I am doing wrong here, any help ?

Comment: You are violating the one definition rule. Make the function inline.

Comment: Are you sure this is C language?  The C language doesn't support `static_cast`.

Comment: Put your functions *declarations* in H files, and functions *definitions* in C files.

Comment: `fflush(NULL);` ? weird.

Comment: Note that, contrary to the implication of the question title, it is not a multiply-defined *macro* that the error message refers to.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio has special handling for logs in a specific format: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxkt8b26.aspx, so you probably want `"%s(%d) : __function\t%s\n"`. Then when you click the line, Visual Studio will take you directly to that function

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre -- not so weird. `fflush(NULL)` flushes all open output streams. Granted, it's overkill, but...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The reason that I use fflush(NULL) is that I call the macro in a multi-thread program, just want to make sure it will be flushed out every time right after the call.

Comment: interesting. thanks for explaining that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with the include guards, you end up with a **definition** of `_show_in_debug` in each compilation unit.  Linking those units then results to a multiple definition error.

For a debugging function like this, define the function as `static` so that it is not visible outside its compilation unit:

```
static void _show_in_debug(const char *_file, unsigned int _line,
        const char *_function, const char *_msg)
{
    printf("%s\t%d\t%s\t%s\n", _file, _line, _function, _msg);
    fflush(NULL);
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 `inline` won't prevent a multiple definition error for a function defined in a header.  `static` will.

Comment: Look at [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). `inline` allows OP's usage.

Comment: It seems this is one of those cases where C differs from C++.  With `gcc` using `inline` gives a multiple definition error, while `g++` accepts it.

Answer (score 3):

If you include that header into more than one .c file, each of them will define the function. That is what the error says.

What you should do is to only declare the function in the header (i.e. only put the prototype there; which you always should) and then define it in a single .c file (i.e. put the body in the .c file), encapsulated into the same switches as the prototype.

Header to be changed to this:

```
/* ... as you quoted ... */
    void _show_in_debug(const char *_file, unsigned int _line,
        const char *_function, const char *_msg);
/* ... rest of what you quoted ... */
```

Code file to contain this:

```
#incude <stdio.h>
#include "Yourheader.h"

#ifdef  NDEBUG
void _show_in_debug(const char *_file, unsigned int _line,
        const char *_function, const char *_msg)
{
    printf("%s\t%d\t%s\t%s\n", _file, _line, _function, _msg);
    fflush(NULL);
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the file header file that you have presented is included in several source files. Why is this a problem? That is because you have defined your _show_in_debug() function in the header instead of *declaring* it in the header and defining it in a source file file. This leads to the function be defined in multiple source files that have included your header.

See http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html for more details (especially, see the "Common Cases" section).